# Create form in popup in Shopify (callback function)

Tags: forms, shopify

I added form to button (in left top in header) https://en.partizanstore.eu/

I checked form in page and it works, but when I added form to snippet and to button, it dont work, dont send letter.

Can anybody help?

And by the way, can I create form anywhere, except on pages?

```
{% capture contact_form %}
<div class="contact">
  {% form 'contact', class: 'contact__form' %}
    {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
      <div class="alert alert--success">
        <span class="alert-title">{{ 'contact.form.successfully_sent' | t }}</span>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if form.errors %}
      <div class="alert alert--error">
        <span class="alert__title">{{ 'general.forms.errors' | t }}</span>
        {% include 'form_errors' %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="form__control">
      <label class="form__label" for="contact__name">{{ [ 'contact.form.name' | t }}</label>
      <input type="text" id="contact__name" name="contact[name]">
    </div>

    <div class="form__control">
      <label class="form__label" for="contact__phone">{{ 'contact.form.phone' | t }}</label>
      <input type="text" id="contact__phone" name="contact[phone]">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="button button--primary" value="{{ 'contact.form.submit' | t }}">
  {% endform %}
</div>
```

{% endcapture %}

Comment: You can create form any where. Can you share how you are using it inside a snippet?

Comment: I added code like in post, in header I create div with button and via data-action="open-mega-search3" call function that create popup with my form inside. But data arent sending((

Comment: your form appears to be posting on `/contact#contact_form` instead of `/contact` . can you check that?